# PowerShell: get list of RDS Collections

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, vdi

Very new to PowerShell here...
I'm trying to use PowerShell to get a complete list of Collection Names from our RDS environment. Preferably, these names would be stored in an array so that I can cycle through the list one collection name at a time.

I found this command:

```
 Get-RDVirtualDesktopCollection -ConnectionBroker $ActiveCB
```

It works, but it displays a pretty table that includes the CollectionName, Type, Size, and PercentInUse.

I don't want a pretty table, I just need the list of Collection Names. I know the above command returns an object of type Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.RDVirtualDesktopCollection, but I'm not sure what to do with that.

How can I produce the list of collection names that I need?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I figure out as soon as I post.
Here's the answer:

Take the returned object and use the property CollectionName. Like this:

```
$foo = Get-RDVirtualDesktopCollection -ConnectionBroker $ActiveCB  
echo $foo[0].CollectionName
```

Much simpler than I made it out originally...

Comment: You could potentially just do: `(Get-RDVirtualDesktopCollection -ConnectionBroker $ActiveCB).CollectionName` - *if it doesn't return an array*.